Recursive definition of a set.

The question is:- Give the recursive definition for the set of all strings of $0$’s and 1’s that have the same number of $0$’s as 1’s.

The answer in my book is:
Let S be the set of all strings of $0$’s and 1’s with the same number of $0$’s and 1’s. The following is a recursive definition for S.
I. Base: The null string $\lambda\in$ S.
II. Recursion: If  $s\in$ S, then

a. $01s$ $\in$ S


b. $s01\in$ S


c. $10s\in$ S


d. $s10\in$ S


e. $0s1\in$ S


f. $1s0\in$ S

III. Restriction: There are no elements of S other that
those obtained from the base and recursion for S.
But I don't understand how the recursion rules are obtained at all. Is there a specific method to find all these out? I tried to find them but it doesn't cover all possible strings. This exercise is given before set theory.

Typo:  $f.$ should read $1s0\in S$.

I don't immediately see how to get, e.g., $11000011$ in this form (but of course it might be possible).  It seems to me you want a term like $s_1, s_2\in S\implies s_1s_2\in S$  So I suppose the goal might be to prove that this axiom follows from the others (if that's true).

I agree with Lulu. Viewing the $0, 1$ as building paths of $(1, 1), (1, -1)$, we want to find the paths that lead to $(n, 0)$. The recursion tells us we can add a small hill to the start or to the end, add a small valley to the start or to the end, or lob off the start and end of the path if they are opposing. Thus, Lulu's example cannot be achieved. $\quad$ Taking this interpretation, it's also clear how Lulu's addition of "rule g: $s_1 s_2 \in S$" results in a complete classification. (In fact, we just need rules E, F, and G)

I'm still hellishly confused with this. With the wide array of so many examples, how do i find the rules at all?

The idea that the "answer" worked from is that if $S$ is a "balanced" string, then you can build a larger balanced string by adding a $1$ and a $0$ to it. So they tried to list all the ways of adding a $0$ and $1$. Unfortunately, they assumed that adding them only to the outside of $S$ was suffcient to get every balanced string. But lulu's example shows that it is not.

To prove that lulu's string cannot be built using just those rules, note that in all cases listed, there is a $0$ in either the first two or last two characters of the resulting string. Lulu's example does not have any $0$s among those four characters.

@lulu what other rules do you suggest?

Aside from my rule, you need $A:\emptyset\in S$, and $B: s\in S\implies 1s0\in S$ and $C: s\in S\implies 0s1\in S$.  To see that this gets my word, for instance, note that $A,B$ gives us $10\in S$, and then we apply $B$ again to get $1100\in S$.  Similarly, $A, C$ gives us $0011\in S$ and now we can apply my rule, call it $D$, to get $11000011\in S$.  Of course you have to prove that these four rules are exhaustive.

Also:  please correct the typo in your rule $f$.  Right now, your $f$ is just a duplicate of your rule $d$.

As a hint for proving that my rule set (which is the same as the set proposed by @CalvinLin, is exhaustive:  go by induction on the length of the word.  Show, by construction, that you can get all the short good words this way.  Then given a good word, remark that either the first and last characters don't match, in which case the complement of them must be a shorter good word, or they do match in which case the word must be the concatenation of two shorter words.
